# Is this valid equality of two sets $S$ = $\{(x,y)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}^2: (2-x)(2-y)<2(4-x-y)\}$ and $T = \{(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (1,3), (3,1)\}$?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

There is this question about proving the equality of two sets (which comes from each set being a subset of the other):

$S$ = $\{(x,y)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}^2: (2-x)(2-y)<2(4-x-y)\}$

$T = \{(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (1,3), (3,1)\}$

Now I solve $S$'s $x$ condition and get:

$xy < 4$

and I say that this makes it a subset of $T$ because each pair of $T$ has its product of pairs less than $4$. Would this be correct, if not why? Also I proved that $T$ is a subset of $S$ because each of product of its pair satisfies $S$'s condition, which is that the product is less than $4$. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have convinced yourself that $S$ can be rewritten as
$$S=\bigl\{(x,y)\in{\mathbb N}^2\bigm| xy<4\bigr\}\ .$$
Since all elements of $T$ are elements of ${\mathbb N}^2$, and obviously fulfill the condition $xy<4$ it is established that $T\subset S$ (and not the converse, as you seem to believe).

In order to complete the proof that $S=T$ it remains to prove that $S\subset T$. This part is missing in your argument: It still could be that there are pairs $(x,y)\in {\mathbb N}^2$ satisfying $xy<4$, which are not listed in $T$. Now when $xy<4$ then at least one of $x$ and $y$ has to be $<2$. (If both $x$ and $y$ are $\geq2$ then their product is $\geq4$.) Therefore all possible pairs in $S$ are of one of the forms $(1,j)$, $(j,1)$, whereby  $1\leq j<4$. This implies that indeed $S\subset T$.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. However, I was wondering where you got the condition that "when $xy < 4$ then at least one of $x$ and $y$ has to be $< 2$? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, if you could answer my comment to clarify your answer, thanks.

Comment: I have answered your comment in my edit of 09/26.

Comment: Okay, so how did you get the form $(1, j), (j, 1)$? Thanks.

Comment: Also, why can't $(4, 1)$ be a solution of set $S$?

Comment: Because $4\cdot1=4$ is not $<4$. – This is my last word on this matter.

Comment: Okay, also didn't answer the comment before that. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I think the comment before that was a bit more important. Thanks.